# Question templates depending on selected tags

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

Maybe related: [Add requirements for a tag (maybe a template?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16843/add-requirements-for-a-tag-maybe-a-template)

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125613/sql-server-count-records-including-zero-per-ten-minute-intervals) and was a nice user initiative to include create and load scripts, so you could easily start think about a concrete solution for user problem.

My suggestion is: what about to include some template on questions bound to specific tags? For example:

- For SQL questions, that template would to suggest to cite SQL database vendor/version in use, some create script and data sample.
- For regex questions, a data sample should be asked and, if contains "HTML", already suggest to use a parser, or to attach a [blood drop to Cthulhu](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html).
- Some specific tags could to suggest marking a wiki (for books, for example)

Following this, we could to add answers including some test cases and make sure question is fully answered, by helping OP to make better questions.

Comment: I don't think that [Add requirements for a tag (maybe a template?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16843) is "maybe related;" I think it's exactly the same question.

Comment: @balpha, I just added that as reference, because nobody understood that question in first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only template I would like posters to follow is to read this first:

[How to Ask Questions the Smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

After that, the details just take care of themselves.

Comment: Only thing I would like to happen is, September would finally end. After that, the details just take care of themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Why restrict people's creativity? I'm not sure this has been a *huge* issue - people can always request extra info via comments etc, without the system demanding things that aren't actually needed. I **hate** being forced to fill in a form to ask a simple question, and we need to keep it as simple as possible. Quite often the details of which sub-build / revision don't actually matter at all...

Also; new users often need help with tags, so it may not even work for the people who would (on the surface) need it most.

Comment: My point isn't to fill a form, but to offer god question _patterns_. After you spend some time on site, you learn how to write that questions but, for first time users, can be hard to enter enough information. I also do agree that isn't a huge issue.