# Asking Template

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add requirements for a tag (maybe a template?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16843/add-requirements-for-a-tag-maybe-a-template)

Is there any asking template for Stack Exchange websites? If there isn't, maybe we can create it?

I think a good question must have this parts:

---

#### SHORT EXPLANATION OF QUESTION

I want to make this `<div>` invisible. CSS isn't working.

#### CODES

Here is my source codes :

```
<div foo="bar">
etc etc etc
</div>
```

and CSS

```
div{
    some: css;
}
```

#### ERROR MESSAGES

There isn't any error message.

#### WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO EXACTLY

I want to hide this `<div>`, because this will be visible with JavaScript.

#### EXAMPLES

There is a live example on this site: http://www.example.com.

Comment: As a voluntary template to actively pick, I find this a very interesting idea.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36811/question-templates-depending-on-selected-tags