# Creating an FAQ post to answer the CSS question: "How do I center something?"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, canonical-questions

One of the most common CSS questions on Stack Overflow is about [centering](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+center) in some form. It can often be confusing, because there are several interpretations of what it means to be "centered" and each one has its own caveats, but at the same time there are only a handful of solutions. These typically involve:

- `text-align: center;`
- `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;`
- `background-position: center;`
- `vertical-align: center;`

The fact is, there's only so many ways to do it - no matter which kind of centering you mean, or what it is you're centering. It's easier to just answer the question with a quick handout than to spend time finding a duplicate that matches the OP's meaning of "center" or writing an essay on it.

I'd like to be able to point people to a detailed answer that handles as many scenarios as possible, which should cover most if not *all* of these questions. I don't think one exists yet, but it's definitely do-able.

My question to meta is:

- **For those knowledgeable on the subject**: Is this going to be worth the effort or a good idea? Is anyone interested in helping if I create a draft? I'd love some help from other SO users before it "goes live" to avoid any misleading/incorrect information.
- For collaboration before posting, how can/should we work on it? Would this be possible in any way within Stack Overflow, or should it be worked on outside the walls of SO? Is it better to just post the question and let the CW status do it's thing, letting editors fix errors instead of worrying about them in the first draft? I feel like an "FAQ" type question needs to be as perfectly answered as possible.

I thinking this would be a one liner question, followed by about 5 answers that handle each scenario. I don't mean to sound pompous, but I'd like to avoid simple answers or close votes from users who may think the question is a "real question".

Basically, how do (or don't) I go about writing an "FAQ" post?

Comment: Are you looking for a [canonical](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108579/canonical-answers-for-repeated-questions) answer?

Comment: Yes exactly. Something to point everyone to that has all the necessary information, no more and no less. What I'm not sure about is how to go about doing it. Guidelines, etiquette, tagging, collaboration (or not) with other authors, how to make sure the post can be easily found, etc.

Comment: Sometimes feels like these is one of these every 10 minutes. We really do need a catch all solution.