# Can we create a “template question”

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

Copied from http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10382/can-we-create-a-template-question on Ask Ubuntu Meta, as I think this could be applied to all the sites.

Some users (especially first time users) ask completely rubbish questions, such as https://askubuntu.com/questions/486830/wi-fi-on-ubuntu-14-04-hp-g70-laptop, they say "unfortunately wi-fi is not working any ideas on how to fix this". It is one of the broadest questions I've seen, and it's quite frustrating, giving no information in the text.

Could we bring in a feature where the default question asking page for new users isn't this - just one big box...:

[image]

...but is split up, more like this:

[image]

Which gives them more prompts etc. (The image one would suggest a link to imgur) It could be the default for users who have less than 20 rep, to avoid annoyingly uninformative questions. If they got 100 from as an association bonus, then that would be included (i.e. they wouldn't see it), unless one of their questions is flagged, and then they see it, until they had earned 20 (i.e. had 120).

[UnorthodoxGrammar suggested](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/10389/186134) that at the side there could be suggestions based on keywords you've typed, or what you've tagged the posting as. For example if the OP types "Ubuntu won't boot" for the first question box, then the suggestion-box might read "It may be helpful to mention what version of Ubuntu you are running." Not all questions would trigger a suggestion, just some basic common ones. ()

[Wilf suggested](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10382/can-we-create-a-template-question#comment19220_10382) that after the 'what have you done to solve it' box, it could suggest searching for an answer before posting (even providing a link to google/bing searching the title etc). This would make them more likely to search for it.

This is similar, but different to [Revisiting question templates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231827/revisiting-question-templates) as this has different suggestions - it suggests using separate boxes to help avoid some of the problems outlined over on that question.

Comment: @ProgramFOX quite possibly, although this has different suggestions, and  it uses separate boxes to help avoid some of the problems outlined there.

Comment: The questions are both about templates. The templates are just presented in a different way, but that doesn't really make it a non-duplicate question.

Comment: OK, but it does have suggestions - such as wilf's etc. I suppose it is... :) Sorry for time wasting

Comment: @Tim you can add your idea as answer to the original request, I don't think it justifies a separate request. (it doesn't mean you should delete this, dupes are fine)

Comment: Okay, I will consider adding them, although that question was a while ago, I doubt it will be implemented, as not many people have commented / viewed it...