# Instead of triage can we try and change the behavior of new posters?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, question-restrictions

[Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) is being tested on SO but wouldn't it be more useful to change the behavior then a behind the scene task the new users are more than likely not aware of?

---

I have pondered an idea for some time now on a way to get a new user to write a better question. The triage idea is okay but do new users even know their questions are being evaluated? If they don't, how will this method get the user to ask a better question because isn't that the goal?

Would it be possible to have new users see a question that is written and asked correctly when they click ask question? By written and asked correctly, I simply mean a question that shows the problem statement and what the OP has done in trying to solve it so the example questions don't need to be highest voted question just a high quality one. I would propose that the example question is not closeable for 20secs or so this way the new user just can't click past it. A simple prompt afterwords could say does your question illustrate what you have attempted? The example questions could even be related to the tags they select so the example will be related to their level.

If a new user continually post bad questions on their some number of first post, a list of said users could be sent to moderators where they can increase the time limit of viewing the examples questions and not let them leave this new user prompt until they start to take it seriously and show improvement or even short term suspensions.

---

How does triage help a new user? Is the new user told their question was triaged and deemed unsalvageable for the following reasons (list reasons)? If not, how can these users learn what they are doing wrong? Triage is only a benefit to those already in the community since it removes what they deem unfit. How does this help a new users learn question etiquette and norms?

If the goal is not guide or teach new users the right ways to engage in a certain stack exchange site, why allow any more people to sign up?

Comment: Show a blank screen for 20 seconds. They'll read that as much as the one with text.

Comment: @random have you read the last paragraph?

Comment: I think you are underestimating how much some people will ignore, however much you shove it in their face. You can lead a horse to water and all that.

Comment: @Oded Yes, some will ignore it but there will be others who read it.

Comment: You misunderstand. Moderators are not here to coach users.

Comment: @random there is no coaching. I wrote increase time limit or suspension. A user with numerous low quality post gets a question ban anyways. The moderator isn't writing saying do this or that.

Comment: @dustin _If a new user continually post bad questions... a list could be sent to moderators_ This already happens to an extent, there are auto-flags raised if a user has a large # of questions closed.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page)

Comment: @gnat none of answers are serious on that post. Duplicating closing is when your question can be adequately answered on that other post.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @gnat awesome link! I think you should be able to figure out why the two questions aren't a duplicate on your own. It isn't difficult.

Comment: do you expect every new reader to make this "de-duplication effort" themselves? some may prefer to save the energy and simply vote close instead

Comment: @gnat the questions aren't even on the same wave length. Why you think a joke question with joke answers is a duplicate is beyond on me.

Comment: Can you tone it down a little bit?

Comment: @rene there is no tone in text. I am stating the obvious to gnat.

Comment: Triage is sending the question in a queue, either low-quality or close vote where they have  the greatest chance of being provided with either comments or close reasons with links. Plenty of opportunity after that for those new users to revisit [help], resource that were provided when they started to write the question in the first place. I understand that new users sems to have problem with our standardas, I don't see how triage is adding a problem, my impression is it gets the feedback-loop going much quicker. That the majority of those new users refuse to read is beyond repair.

Comment: @dustin that is clear, my comment was just to let you know I have  different opinion.

Comment: @rene I am not implying triage is causing a problem. What I am saying is that some people learn by example better. Why not provide them with high quality examples to learn from? You click ask question, greeting-I see you are new user see an example how a well received question is asked, then question-does your question state what you have tried as well.

Comment: Something like [templates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231827/revisiting-question-templates)?

Comment: @rene on many sites, all we every do is say show your work, add detail, but maybe we should show new users what we consider showing work is or adding detail means to us. What if showing work means something different to them based on where they have a learned? No, not like a template. Those are just statements not physical proof of what we want as a community.

Comment: Well, for SO goes that we are not kindergarten. If the links, guidance and assistance users get when they write a question are simply ignored I'm not sure what else you expect to throw in their face that will make them pay attention. The users that end-up in a ban should maybe get electrocuted if they touch their keyboard and then they still post on meta innocently asking what possibly could be wrong. *Yeah, I got some shocks, I wasn't paying attention. My cat catched fire when it walked across my keyboard it occured to me that something was wrong*.

Comment: @rene our whole lives we are shown what to do. When you get a new job, you have orientation where they show you how do to xyz. When you go to college and/or grad school, the professors show you how to do xyz. When you fill out forms for something, there is usually something showing you how to fill it. Lawyers put sign here stickies on forms for people showing them where to sign. Showing people how to do something correctly is common for non kindergarten adults. What is wrong with considering this or even trying it? What if it works?

Comment: But those examples you use have a strict context and have a limited variability. To translate that to SO you would need a finite set of characteristics to guide the new user along the path that helps it to create the first great question in their tag / for their problem.

Comment: @rene triage could be used on already answered question to have users vote on questions that qualify in tags for candidacy as a high quality question. Once there is a handful of questions giving the go ahead as high quality, we have our list. I think of more than SO. Any sight that has has the potential for question without work would want this: math, physics, bio, etc where people post no effort give me answer questions.

Comment: if you're interested in more serious discussion, this one suggests that there is work in progress on it: [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773): "Additional just-in-time help (triggered while writing a question) is in the works..." (side note looking at [profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) of a guy who asked that "8-ball" feature makes one suspect that this old funny idea wasn't only air rattling and is not quite unrelated to these recent works)

Comment: ...FWIW some (simplest and relatively minor yet) parts of this in-the-works stuff already "leaked" into the system: [all caps warnings and tag tool tips](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ZTY.png "screen shot taken at Programmers showing how these work")

Comment: Related to your proposed feature: [Show examples of good and bad questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179268)

Answer (score 10):

**Triage *does* help.**

We can't help every user. We don't have the manpower or the time. Triage strips off the cruft of the people we *can* help, and gives us the ability to help them.

Triage picks the people that need just a *little* guidance to become great contributors. Then, we can give them the nudges they need. This is much more rewarding for both parties - people who improve, and people who help - by making efforts worth more return.

As for the people whose posts are "Unsalvageable" - consider that they've been offered pages of information on how to make their posts better, and either read none of it, or read it and didn't understand it. But we don't have unlimited resources to help people - we want to make the process as rewarding and effective as possible, and that means focusing effort where it will help most.

Comment: Showing new posters what a properly formatted question with question statement and effort looks like eats up unlimited resources?

Comment: @dustin There are two types of new users: those that care and those that don't. Those that care already figure it out. Those that don't care will never get it no matter how much hand-holding they get. We do not want those users. The Triage isn't to help those that don't care, it's to help us get rid of them so they stop dragging down the quality of the site.

Comment: @Mysticial I agree that we don't want those that dont care but some people who would care don't know better. We should want those people since they have the potential to be better, but if we are throwing the baby out with the bath water, we will miss those users and only get the better suited new posters when the others need just a little bit more help then their better suited counterpart to be just as good.

Comment: @dustin For those that care, there are already tons of resources that help them. They will actually *read* the text and banners they are presented with before they ask a question - which is more than enough info. Those that don't care, (i.e desperate help vampires), will do everything they can to get rid of those banners and post a question asap. No they do not read a single word on them. Those users we want out.

Answer (score 9):

It's not an either/or question. Triage helps, but we're still exploring additional ideas like providing better, more detailed step-by-step guidance for new askers. (Though it's important to keep in mind that no matter what we do in terms of providing excellent information to read...some people will just see a box and start typing. Some amount of that is unavoidable.)

Comment: I know that is why I proposed the time to see good questions increases if users dont learn. Eventually, they will either adhere or have to wait looking at an example question for an hour or more before they can ask a question. At that point, it would be better to conform.

Comment: @dustin The help center is already full of lots of good example questions for people to look at.

Comment: @Servy by the fact that triage is even being tested, shows us we are beyond help center tactics.

Comment: @dustin Yes, as Laura and many others have told you, some people just refuse to be taught how to ask a good question.  Those interested in seeing the examples can see them, those that aren't won't be affected by your proposal.

Comment: @Servy not everyone who is willing to learn is going to root around in the help center. Why is everyone so opposed to trying? This could be affective but there so much negative to wanting to show new users the right way to do something. I learn better from examples and I bet others do too and the may even appreciate it. Everyone is **assuming** showing examples wont work.

Comment: @dustin Users are forced to go through the help center before they are allowed to ask a question.  Again, users *are* being shown the right way to do things, many times, in lots of places; they are ignoring everything they see.  Adding *yet another* thing that they're going to ignore isn't going to accomplish much.  The whole point here is we're *already doing* almost exactly what you're proposing, and have been for years.  It just don't help much at all.

Comment: @Servy that is SO only being forced into the help center, correct? I am thinking of a global use for this not just SO. Plus, when a user is a ready to ask a question, they are paying more attention to prompts compared to when they are signing up. The reason they would pay more attention then is because they want to get a question out to the community. When you sign up, you just want to get through it to get to where you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see with your approach is the presence of variety of subjects.

What is considered a good research with one subject may be inadequate for another or sometimes research on the subject may even be impossible.

So to be correctly implemented, for each tag a good question must be posted, which may also prove inadequate - due to the nature of the question. A "What" question is very different from a "Why" or a "How" question.

It is impossible for a new user to understand and apply the same to his/her question with just one good quality question. This may cause some excellent questions to go unposted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another variation of this could be something like "Try to enhance the [new-user](/questions/tagged/new-user) experience"? Something I'm trying to get going via:

- Questions such as my [What are the recommended activities for a new user, such as for asking for more info on a question or an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/what-are-the-recommended-activities-for-a-new-user-such-as-for-asking-for-more)
- Various wiki edit suggestions, with my related question [Is iterative refinement of the same wiki tag/excerpt with more than just minor fixes OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251378/is-iterative-refinement-of-the-same-wiki-tag-excerpt-with-more-then-just-minor-f)

Be aware, I feel like rather a newbie, even unsure if posting this answer (suggestion) is the right thing to do. And if the feedback to my answer here turns out to be a mistake from me, I'm even not sure what my best reaction then should be (hopefully "delete my answer" will be allowed, as a kind of last resort, like "let's get out of here"). This is just to illustrate my perception that SE does not appear to me like a newbie friendly / forgiving place. And there is so much docu and features to digest and to get familiar with, so maybe all parties involved (new and anciens) each need to contribute their part of it all?

Answer (score 0):

As Emrakul stated, Triage does serve a useful purpose. Some questions that get filtered by it include spam, blatantly off-topic questions, etc; these are the kind of the stuff we do not want on a site. Without the Triage, it would take much longer to sort the information and deal with it properly.

If the post is salvageable, but not perfect, that allows for the reviewer and editor to try to improve their posts in the future. Once again, Triage acts as a way to communicate between the Community and the user.

One thing I would suggest though is perhaps a notification of some sort that a user's question is being reviewed.

All in all, Triage helps everyone:

- It helps the user learn the site and improve
- It helps older members to quickly guide newer users
- It gives moderators more time to deal with more important concerns
- It leads to more time answering questions that matter rather than the same, pointless questions thatcould easily be found searching.