# Question prompts for new users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add requirements for a tag (maybe a template?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16843/add-requirements-for-a-tag-maybe-a-template)

Would it be beneficial to include a predefined set of headers in the question text area that prompt new users (under 100 rep) of the basic information required to solve most programming problems?

Many questions on SO, asked by new users, are essentially:

> Help! My family cat died, but the problem is that I am trying to write fizz buzz
>   with AmazingLanguage and it doesn't work. Please help me! KThxBye.

Everyone knows that this question is impossible to answer. And so SO users reply with:

> Show me the code.

I propose the following as a template for *new users*:

---

### Problem

*Describe what you want to do.*

### Source Code

*Paste what you have developed; type **CTRL-k** to format the code.*

### Errors

*Paste error messages here, or describe the errors.*

### Resolution

*How have you tried to fix the problem yourself?*

### Question

*What would you like to know?*

---

The format I use on `tex.stackexchange.com` is quite similar:

---

### Background

*Describe what I am trying to do.*

### Problem

*Describe the difficultly I encountered; show the code.*

### Related

*Post related links.*

### Question

*Ask how to resolve the problem, or different approaches.*