# Any way to detect a duplicate for picture questions

Tags: support, search, duplicate-questions, images

Is it possible to detect if a question is duplicate, when the question is asking about a picture? For example, if I stick a picture onto the question and ask "what is this", is there any way for me to check if that question is a duplicate? If there is, what is the method? If there is not, then it will be very inconvenient. The picture question may result in a duplicate close and if I ask a lot of picture questions, then I will be banned for asking too much duplicate questions!

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean if a question with exact pic exist?.. Not really clear question.

Comment: Nearly exact / similar questions asking the same thing

Comment: ... are called duplicates. So what? Do you want to search by image? If the title is like "What is this" I doubt if searching there will give you any meaningful results.

Comment: Trying to search by images... Yes. Exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen a case where this would make sense. Do you have any examples of times when this would have been useful for you?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen It would be useful for [identification-request](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)s on anime.se, for example.

Comment: @nicael That's what I was thinking, but is there enough coverage by those to actually make it plausible that you'd get a hit? It'd certainly be handy if it worked, I just can't imagine there are nearly as many questions and answers on there as there would be available images of any given show or movie, which means it would be rare to find a viable result. But I don't use any sites that do those, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Matt It will turn out in practice :)

Comment: @nicael doesn't system show a [warning for askers of these questions](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/1084) over there at Anime?

Comment: @gnat didn't know about it, and anime.se was just an example, another example would be [identification](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) on bricks.se. Is this feature enabled elsewhere?

Comment: @nicael process to create tag-tip is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242252/automatic-warnings-of-dangerous-tags/242355#comment792260_242355): "Post a [feature-request] for each tag, with specific guidance... and justification for needing something more than the tag excerpt. Let folks discuss it..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible to search for a pic with advanced search or dupe search (while asking, below the title).

You can try google search by image:

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url={your-image-url}?&q=site:somesite.stackexchange.com
```

`{your-image-url}` would be image you want to find;
`somesite.stackexchange.com` - replace it with some SE site you want to search on.